# Is my tagging technique correct?

Tags: php, mysql, normalization, tagging

Here is my table structure
**tags table**

```
ID------ TAG_NAME
1         PHP
2         MYSQL
```

**article table**

```
ID----- ART_TITLE -- CATEGORY ---    TAGS    --- CREATED_ON
1       some title1     22         ["1","2"]       13258465
2       some title2     23         ["4","5"]       13258465
3       some title3     21         ["5","7"]       13258465
```

The tags values are json array.
I'm stucked with display articles with tag ID. Can anyone tell me how can I do it or which method do I need to use.

Comment: JSON won't be easily searchable and it's not normalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have an `article_tags` (with two columns, `tag_id` and `article_id`) table that associates tags to articles in a normalized manner. Having the tags as a JSON array isn't indexable, searchable, etc.